# how can i do a google search in adress bar from clipboard memory with autohotkey languages

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, clipboard, autohotkey

I want do a **google search** in **adress bar** from the active browser that i use, On my windows 10 system.

The autohotkey (AHK) macro script must do this:

- copy the selected text to clipboard memory
- goto the adress bar
- a - put the text https://www.google.com/search?q=
- b - put the clipboard memory text
- c - put the google parameter text &lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=50

a+b+c

And then if i click <kbd>F2</kbd> it must can do, direct a **google search** with parameters

I need a command that can goto the **adress bar** in browsers like (**google chrome**) or other browsers (the active one)

This script code can not do that. it does not go to the **adress bar**

```
; ^ = Ctrl 
; ! = Alt
; + = Shift
; # = Win (Windows logo key)

f2:: ; press f2 for a google search
send ^c 
send https://www.google.com/search?q=%clipboard%&lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=50
send {enter}
return
```

Comment: Ctrl+L is the shortcut that works for both Firefox and Chrome if I recall correctly. Doesn't really warrant a full answer.

Comment: F6 does it too.

Comment: CTRL+L this is **what i want**, i wil only need to insert a line into my code **SEND ^l ; CTRL+L **- thanks

Comment: Fair enough, I posted a better script that uses your technique, but it's likely much than what ever you have come up thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox

#If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")

    F2::
        commands := ["{Ctrl Down}cl", "v{Ctrl Up}{enter}"]
        clipPrev := clipboard
        sleep 10
        for e, v in commands {
        SendInput % v
        sleep 10
        clipboard := A_Index == 1 
            ? format("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=50"
            , clipboard)
            : clipPrev                           
        }
    return
```

Comment: this is **almost** what i want, but this works only if i have did open my default browser. not to other browsers or active browser - i will use my own script and insert a line  **SEND ^l ; CTRL+L** see Elliot DeNolf - but thanks any way for this answer

Comment: ahkcoder i see that you did change your script. but i think that my new script is easy for beginners to understand. and it works in all browser without using a class name.

Comment: Anyone who reads the AHK Documentation could add a browser to the Group. Your code works in non-browsers, meaning it could have unforeseen consequences. My code isolates that issue and is the best answer, regardless of if "beginners" could understand it.

Comment: I did test it out for days on browsers like Edge,Internet Explorer,chrome,firefox,Iron and it works without problems - i think that you mean with unforeseen consequences issue [that if a **default function shortcut CTRL+T does do changed** in **one** of the **browsers** that it then **does not work**] [function 1 - load times to open a new tab] [function 2 - load times to goto the adress bar] [function 3 - automatic select the text in adress bar] the command **sleep** does solved this issue.

Comment: If you means that the script only must work in browsers and not in other applications, then it is fair to say, **ahkcoder** you are right about that. use the command **GroupAdd** - i did update my answer - but my script did do the same thing. and it is easy to explain for beginners.